# Quem é o principal criador do Stack?

Tags: debate, stackoverflow, stackexchange

Sempre tive dúvida em saber quem foi o principal criador do Stack Overflow. Esse cara é mito! :)

Comment: Joel Spolsky e Jeff Atwood. Joel também criou o Trello, aparentemente

Comment: Parabéns a eles, simplesmente solucionaram a vida de muitos programadores!!!

Comment: Os blogs deles são respectivamente https://www.joelonsoftware.com/ e [Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/)

Answer (score 16):

Tudo pode [ser visto na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) ([resumo em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow)).

[Joel Spolsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) ex-funcionário da Microsoft responsável pelo Excel e que já tinha uma empresa de produtos para desenvolvedores que era divulgada por talvez o [blog mais famoso de desenvolvimento de software](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/), escrito por ele, se juntou com o [Jeff Atwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) que tinha o que talvez seja o [segundo blog mais famoso de desenvolvimento de software](https://blog.codinghorror.com/) e fizeram um site para ajudar desenvolvedores que não tinham uma opção sem ruídos e sem cobranças.

Dalí surgiram outros [sites derivativos](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), outros produtos como o [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab), [Enterprise](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise), [Channels](https://stackoverflow.com/channels) e outros já defuntos.

[O anúncio do Jeff](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/) que partiu para outros projetos. E [o anúncio do Joel](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/04/16/stackoverflowcom/) que ainda é CEO da empresa, já criou outros projetos, inclusive já vendidos.

[Time atual da empresa](https://stackoverflow.com/company/management).

Muito mais informação pode ser obtida no chamado [metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Não há dúvida que foi uma revolução. Mas há [críticas](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=2608) ([no metão tem várias](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254355/140010)) e piadas sobre a sua existência.

E [nem tudo são flores no desenvolvimento da empresa](https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/02/stack-overflow-lays-off-staff/).

Comment: *Unrelated*: Você leu a resposta da crítica no Metão? Gostei da idéia do curso não oficial: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly é bem legal, quem sabe alguém faça em pt (estou pensando em fazer, mas não será tão já).

Answer (score 11):

[Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky), em colaboração com [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) criaram o [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), que foi o primeiro e até hoje é o maior site da rede StackExchange, que hoje é uma rede com mais de 160 sites Q&A.

Como disse o rray em comentário, ambos escrevem em seus respectivos blogs.
Joel escreve no  [joelonsoftware.com](http://joelonsoftware.com) e Jeff escreve no [Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/)

Aparentemente, Joel também criou o [Trello](http://trello.com), e Jeff está trabalhando em uma plataforma de discussão online chamada Discourse.

Answer (score 8):

Na página "Sobre" da [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about) e do [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company) já é comentado sobre isso:

> [Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/about-me/), então CEO da *Fog Creek Software* e autor do blog amplamente lido, [Joel on Software](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/), chamou [Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/codinghorror), também conhecido pelo seu popular blog  [Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/), com a ideia de iniciar um site Q&A.
>
> Então em 2008, Joel Spolsky e Jeff Atwood lançam o Stack Overflow.

Jeff Atwood, o associado de [número 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) do Stack Overflow, [não trabalha mais na Stack Exchange](https://blog.codinghorror.com/farewell-stack-exchange/), devido ao início de uma família e a atenção que é necessária ser dada aos filhos:

> *Durante muito tempo, o trabalho era minha única preocupação. Trabalhei noites, fins de semana e natal. Naqueles raros momentos em que eu não estava no trabalho no corpo, eu estava lá no espírito, incapaz de falar ou pensar em mais nada.*
>
> *A vida inicial é difícil para as famílias. Acabamos de receber dois novos membros em nossa família, e correr o mais rápido possível pode não ser sustentável para pais de múltiplos filhos pequenos.*

Já Joel Spolski, o [4º associado do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) é o atual [CEO das comunidades Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/company/management).

Atualmente a Stack Exchange conta com 171 comunidades dos mais diversos tópicos e assuntos, as quais você pode ver [neste link](https://stackexchange.com/sites).